# rust_serialize error: the type of this value must be known in this context

Tags: rust

The example below is not working, but I can't figure out why:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use rustc_serialize::json;

fn main() {

    let json_str = "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}";
    let foo: String = json::decode(&json_str).unwrap().as_object().get("foo").unwrap().as_string().unwrap();
    println!("{}", foo);

}
```

Error:

```
src/main.rs:8:23: 8:67 error: the type of this value must be known in this context
src/main.rs:8     let foo: String = json::decode(&json_str).unwrap().as_object().get("foo").unwrap().as_string().unwrap();
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I think at the very least error is pointing to the wrong location here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get a `Json`, you cannot use `json::decode` since `Json` does not implement `Decodable`.

But you can do the following:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use rustc_serialize::json::Json;

fn main() {
    let json_str = "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}";
    let json = Json::from_str(&json_str).unwrap();
    let foo = json.as_object().unwrap().get("foo").unwrap().as_string().unwrap();
    println!("{}", foo);
}
```